# Deleting a JHipster user

Tags: jpa, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I try to add the delete feature for a user in a JHipster project. But when I delete the user entity the following exception occurs :
Referential integrity constraint violation:

`"FK_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_NAME: PUBLIC.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN FOREIGN KEY(USER_NAME) REFERENCES PUBLIC.T_USER(LOGIN)"`

How can I delete the record in the OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN table before deleting the user, please ?

Comment: which version you are using JHipster.

Comment: My current JHipster version is 2.11.1 but I don't know if it was this version used to generate the project

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have implemented by getting a tokenStore reference and removing the tokens for the user before removing the user

```
@Inject
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable Long id){
                    User user = userRepository.findOne(id);

                    log.debug("Account tokens ("+id+") deletion");
                    Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName("clienid", user.getLogin());
                    for (OAuth2AccessToken token : tokens) {
                        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(token);
                    }

                    log.debug("Account ("+id+") deletion");
                    userRepository.delete(user);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the database in front of me at this moment, but you as might as well just query OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN by the user you wish to delete. Hence, you delete such row from OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN table. Then, you should be good to delete the desired user.

Comment: Which entity to use to do the deletion ? I can't see any domain entity or repository linked to this table :(

Comment: There's not an explicit JHipster entity for this. This is just an utility table to store the access tokens when using oauth. The steps I mentioned above have to be done directly in the database. You'll have to open a database client, run a query to get the oauth token related to the user you want to delete. Once found, you delete this record. Then, you should be able to delete the corresponding user.

Comment: Is there any proper way to do it ? Using the a Spring Security OAuth API for instance ?